I am installing a fan with light in my room, the existing light has red and black wire and red and white wire from switch in Australia
I am installing a fan with light in my room, it has a live, neutral and ground connection on the fan plate, my wall switch has a red and white wire running to the ceiling and I have a red and black wire running from a junction in the ceiling to the light fitting, what wires do I connect up

did the fan come with instructions

Are you saying that the wall switch has nothing but a single pair of wires, and they are red and white? That sounds unusual. ¶ "a red and black wire running from a junction", but what else is in the junction and what are those two wires connected to? ¶It would help a lot if you could provide diagrams showing everything at each of the boxes.

Does this fan have a wireless remote control? What is the colour of the live and the neutral on your 'fan plate'? Do you plan to control the fan and the light with the wall switch or some other means, e.g., pull chains or wireless remote that comes with the fan?

Could be that the house live and neutral are in the junction box. The live goes down to the switch and comes back to the junction box as a switched live. The neutral and the switched live (one red and one black) go from the junction box to the location of the fan. you would need a test device to determine which is which. What is the colour code for live and for neutral in Australia?

Is black the colour code for neutral in Australia?

The fan has a brown (live), a blue (Neutral) and green (ground). The wall switch has only the red and white wires and the junction box in the ceiling has other cables connected and running to other lights for other rooms, the red and black running to this light fitting is the last one. The fan and light is operated by a remote control, the switch is just to turn on the power or turn off.  Red is Live in Australia and black is neutral.  Hope this helps,
